# Invalid syntax (Py 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[My Discord Bot code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oj40.png)

I'm fairly new to coding and am trying to make a discord bot. I'm not sure why this code is not running though, the terminal says that the 'if' is invalid but from previous experiences in simple coding it has always worked. Would be thankful to anyone who can help.

```
#Python 3.6
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(commands_prefix='#')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

    @client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run('NTA4NjE2MjkwNzE4NzExODA4.DsEiuA.gmMBw3TUxLZJ5puM1Snco_DZWKU'
)
```

Comment: Dont't post your code as an image but rather inline in your question.

Comment: Post your code as part of the question rather than as an image

Answer (score 1):

`@client.event` is a function decorator (because of the `@`). It must be followed by a function definition, to which the decorator will be applied.

Comment: @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)